# C# dispose unmanaged object stored in managed collection

Tags: c#, .net, destructor, dispose, idisposable

In my class I have unmanaged objects in managed collection (*pendingFramesBuffer*). I need to implemented IDisposable interface.

My question: Where I need to clear *pendingFramesBuffer* collection? In the *if (disposing) {...}* condition or not.

```
public class Example : IDisposable
{
    // unmanaged pointer in managed collection
    private BlockingCollection<IntPtr> pendingFramesBuffer = new BlockingCollection<IntPtr>();

    /// SOME CODE TO FILL pendingFramesBuffer COLLECTION

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
        
            }

            // CLEAR pendingFramesBuffer COLLECTION
            while (pendingFramesBuffer != null && pendingFramesBuffer.Count > 1)
            {
                var tookFrameBuffer = pendingFramesBuffer.Take();
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(tookFrameBuffer);
            }

            this.disposed = true;
        }
    }

    ~Example()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use `SafeHandle` instead of `IntPtr`?

Comment: Using `SafeHandle` would be much better. It lets you avoid the finalizer and the `disposing` flag. The `disposing` flag is there so you can avoid disposing objects that themselves are managed and have finalizers; it doesn't apply to your unmanaged objects and so you would put the release of the unmanaged resources _outside_ the `disposing` check. See duplicate for those details and more. If you switch to `SafeHandle`, you can get rid of the finalizer altogether, as well as the `disposing` flag and any code executed only within that check. But you'll still release your unmanaged memory.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for advice, I tried to use the SafeHandle, but it's not suite for me. I work with frames, and if I don't clear buffer by yourself the memory very fast fulled, it has time to fill up to 7-8 GB before GC cleans it.